# I want to use hijack in golang, while get invalid response on client

Tags: go

I want to use hijack in golang, while recieve invalid response on client

```golang
func hijack(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("start")

    hj, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)

    fmt.Println(ok)

    c, buf, err := hj.Hijack()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    n, err := buf.Write([]byte("hello"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("n == ",n)

    err = buf.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

follow printed on server:

```
start

true

n ==  5

end
```

but I got following error on the client

> localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `Hijacker`'s documentation says

> Hijack lets the caller take over the connection.              After a
>   call to Hijack the HTTP server library                will not do
>   anything else with the connection.
>                                                                 It becomes the caller's responsibility to manage              and close
>   the connection.
>                                                                 The returned net.Conn may have read or write deadlines        already set,
>   depending on the configuration of the            Server. It is the
>   caller's responsibility to set              or clear those deadlines
>   as needed.
>                                                                 The returned bufio.Reader may contain unprocessed buffered    data from
>   the client.
>                                                                 After a call to Hijack, the original Request.Body must not    be used. The
>   original Request's Context remains valid and     is not canceled until
>   the Request's ServeHTTP method          returns.

You need to write to `c` rather than `buf`. And you need to write response status and `Content-Length` header.

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("start")

    writer.Header().Add("Content-Length", "5")
    writer.WriteHeader(200)
    hj, ok := writer.(http.Hijacker)

    fmt.Println(ok)

    c, _, err := hj.Hijack()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    n, err := c.Write([]byte("hello"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("n == ",n)

    err = c.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("end")
})
```